# Vnode associated file protection bits

Tags: freebsd

I have a vnode and I want to get the protection bits (sticky bit, write bit, etc.) of its associated file. I know I can get the vnode's `vattr` struct which contains a field called `u_short va_mode;  /* files access mode and type */`.

However, I was wondering if this is the same thing as the vnode's associated file's `mode_t st_mode; /* inode protection mode */`. Does anybody know if these would be the same for a given vnode and its associated file?

My final goal is to see if a sticky bit is set for a vnode's assocated file.

Answer (score 0):

The st_mode in struct stat is set from the vnode's va_mode, with the addition of a flag based on vnode type (eg VREG or VDIR).  Take a look at http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/vfs_vnops.c#L1428; that's the piece of code that fills in the struct stat.